# Why i am unable to view the values of XMLTYPE data type column in Oracle SQL Developer grid?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, xmltype

I am using Oracle DB version 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 and SQL Developer version 18.1.0.095.
When i run the query against the table as below
SELECT USER_DATA fROM table1;
all i get as output in the grid is (XMLTYPE). I am unable to view the value of the XMLTYPE data type column in Oracle SQL Developer grid.
I have changed the setting in SQL Developer by checking the "Display XML value in Grid" also but no luck so far. Can someone pls suggest how to view in the grid?

```
create table TEST_SOLACE_EXT_QTABLE (
       SENDER_PROTOCOL  number,
       USER_DATA        SYS.XMLTYPE,
       USER_PROP        sys.anydata
)
pctfree 10 pctused 0 initrans 1 maxtrans 255 xmltype column USER_DATA store as basicfile binary xml (
       tablespace users
       enable storage in row
       chunk 8192
       retention
       nocache logging
       storage ( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL
       DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT )
)
ALLOW NONSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA;
```

Thanks & Regards
Gautam

Comment: what happens when you double click on the (XMLTYPE) cell? Your DB and your SQLDev are both quite old...but, can you provide an example of how TABLE1 is defined?

Comment: col_name USER_DATA data_type XMLTYPE. When i double click still (XMLTYPE) only hets displayed. Upon clicking on the pencil icon a small blank window opens up with nothing in it. I tried clicking on the download and editor options in that blank window, but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: there's a half dozen ways you can implement xmltype, share the ddl of your table in the question please

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEST.TEST_SOLACE_EXT_QTABLE 
   (
 SENDER_PROTOCOL NUMBER, 
 USER_DATA SYS.XMLTYPE , 
 USER_PROP SYS.ANYDATA 
   ) USAGE QUEUE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  XMLTYPE COLUMN USER_DATA STORE AS BASICFILE BINARY XML (
  TABLESPACE TS_TEST ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION 
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ALLOW NONSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA;

Comment: It's working for me (database 19c and sql developer 20.2) - do you see any messages/errors in the log panels?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith In the logging page i am getting the following error: SEVERE 8798 10267 oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.ReferenceWorker$PBEWorker Password decryption failed for connection RCMSDIS_23.